# OOAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token, restfb, facebook-java-api

I am using restfb java sdk for adding facebook login in my app
i have already created a test app but when i try to get the detail of the user following error message displayed

```
[FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. (code 2500, subcode null)]
```

here is my code

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load()  
    val FBAppId = config.getString("fb.app.id")
      val FBAppSecret = config.getString("fb.app.secretkey")
      val aceessToken = new DefaultFacebookClient().obtainAppAccessToken(FBAppId, FBAppSecret)
    log.info("token is "+aceessToken.getAccessToken)
    val facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(aceessToken.getAccessToken)
    val fbuser = facebookClient.fetchObject("me",classOf[User] ,Parameter.`with`("fields", "id,name,email, first_name , last_name"))
    log.info("name : {} ", fbuser.getName)
    log.info("User first  name :{} ", fbuser.getFirstName)
    log.info("User last name : {}" , fbuser.getLastName)
    log.info("User Email : {}" , fbuser.getEmail)
```

here is the access token printed on console

```
 token is 587299244766256|udH5HgYve1DHGjKHU55hBw9Ik5Y
```

(i think this in not correct as i have read in Facebook docs that access token consists of 150 characters and the token that is generating is not 150 character long )
and in this line

```
val fbuser = facebookClient.fetchObject("me",classOf[User] ,Parameter.`with`("fields", "id,name,email, first_name , last_name"))
```

the exception thrown

```
[FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. (code 2500, subcode null)]
```

please help me how can i get the details of logged in users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fetch the endpoint `me` with an app access token. You need a user or page access token.